# Plugin Initializing failure for JTS

Tags: solr, jts

I am new in Solr.
I install Solr 5.5.0 on my Ubuntu server and it was running fine until I tried to install JTS.

I download the JTS library and placed it under "/opt/solr-5.5.0/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib".

I tried the following code in my managed-schema file:

```
<fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType" spatialContextFactory="org.locationtech.spatial4j.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory" geo="true" distanceUnits="kilometers"/>
```

and also this:

```
<fieldType name="bbox" class="solr.BBoxField" spatialContextFactory="org.locationtech.spatial4j.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"
        geo="true" distanceUnits="kilometers" numberType="_bbox_coord" />
<fieldType name="_bbox_coord" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" docValues="true" stored="false"/>
```

But when I am trying to access my Solr through the browser, it's giving me following error:

Can't load schema /var/solr/data/mykeywords/conf/managed-schema: Plugin Initializing failure for [schema.xml] fieldType

Not sure what's going wrong here, can anyone please suggest me any solution?

Comment: Are you sure the JTS version you downloaded is compatible with such an old version of Solr? Have you tried it against 6.x? Are there any errors about what the initialization failure is?

Comment: Upgraded to the latest version and everything is working fine now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Sachin Nagpal could please provide me the version you installed, a link to download ?